# How to create an Image with non-root access from a Dockerfile for OpenShift?

Tags: docker, openshift

I need to create an image from a docker file with non-root permission, because I don't have root access on our OpenShift Container Platform. Root access is forbidden by our service provider. When I try to pull the image from docker hub:

https://s19.directupload.net/images/191029/2vvyrpw2.jpg

Container is not runing, because it's need root access.

https://s19.directupload.net/images/191029/f42sreci.jpg

I tried to re-build the image and changed the permission of the path.

Docker File:

`RUN set -x \
   && chmod g+rx /usr/local/HelpSystems/GoAnywhere/jre/bin/java`

I get this error now:

`/usr/local/HelpSystems/GoAnywhere/tomcat/bin/../../jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I create an image with non-root-access?

Answer (score 1):

By default, OpenShift does not allow containers to run as `root`. This is a great security feature from Red Hat.

When creating a Docker image using a `Dockerfile`, I always create a `non-root` user:

1. Create a non-root user (`USER 1001`) when running a command to perform some action in your Dockerfile: `RUN a,b,c`
2. At the end of my Dockerfile, I will set `USER 1001` so the container will run as the 1001 user, i.e. non-root.

If you need a container to run as `root`,

1. Create the image off the OpenShift platform
2. Grant [privileged access](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#grant-access-to-the-privileged-scc) to the container. I would not recommend this.

Comment: Thank you. When I add this to my docker file and try to created an image.

`RUN groupadd -g 999 application && \

    useradd -r -u 999 -g application application

USER application`

I'm getting an error "GID '999' already exists" operations is crushing.,

Error: https://i.ibb.co/myGtFh9/Unbenannt.jpg

Comment: Before the RUN, I would do USER 1001.

Comment: I add USER 1001 before RUN..I get the some error again
´groupadd: GID '999' already exists
The command '/bin/sh -c groupadd -g 999 application &&     useradd -r -u 999 -g application application' returned a non-zero code: 4´